# Trying to create a dynamic array in the below mentioned json format

Tags: php, json, laravel, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create an a JSON response in this format:

```
{
  "id": "",
  "goalLink": [{
       "iconUrl": "",
       "title": ""
  }]
}
```

I declared the variables as

```
$id;
$goalLink = [];
```

Then within a constructor i created

```
$this->id = 123;
$this->goalLink = [
     'iconUrl' => null,
     'title' => null
];
```

now when i do something like this in a function

```
public function example() {
    $client = API::client();
    $url = "some url here";
    $data = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'goalLink' => [
            'iconUrl' => $this->goalLink['iconUrl'],
            'title' => $this->goalLink['title'] 
        ] 
    ];
    $client->post($url, ['json' => $data]);

}
```

but this is the $data format what the example() is sending to the API

```
{
  "id": "",
  "goalLink": {
       "iconUrl": "",
       "title": ""
  }
}
```

I checked in various other forums but could not find a solution. Can someone please help me out here. I am not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the fields are empty ?

Comment: no u see above the format of the json it has a [ ] after goalLink: ... Which basically means its a dynamic array.. but i am not able to pass data in that format i am getting a { } after goalLink: ...

Comment: try to do: `$client->post( $url, [ 'json' => json_encode($data) ] );`

Comment: No it still sends the data in the same format

Comment: Reading here http://www.json.org/ I would say it is not possible. {} are used to indicate objects = name/value pairs, like so { "name" : "value" } and []  are used to indicate arrays = collections of values, like so [ "value1", "value2"]. So from what I understand you're trying to use [] where JSON says it uses {}. My question is why?

Comment: I corrected the expected json format in the question above. According to the json format this [{ }] means a dynamic array right ??

Comment: https://3v4l.org/4jp5l

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks. That works fine. I was missing an inner [ ] in goalLink[ ] :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your associative array with iconUrl and title inside an indexed array would provide the additional wrapper.

```
public function example() {
    $client = API::client();
    $url = "some url here";
    $data = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'goalLink' => [
            [
                'iconUrl' => $this->goalLink['iconUrl'],
                'title' => $this->goalLink['title'] 
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $client->post($url, ['json' => $data]);
}
```